# I keep getting a error saying cannot find symbol - variable keyboard

Tags: java

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Map{
  public static void main(String[] args){ 

  // create a Scanner object 
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 //Prompt the user to enter three numbers in inches 
 System.out.print("enter four numbers:");
 double distance1 = input.nextDouble();
 double distance2 = input.nextDouble();
 double distance3 = input.nextDouble();
double distance4 = input.nextDouble();

 //public classify DistanceScale

    //Make a constant to hold kilometers to miles conversion
    //final const MILESTOKILOS = 1.609344;

    // Explain the program to the user
    System.out.println("Welcome! This program calculates true distance from map measurements You can enter up to 4 distances");
    System.out.println();

    // ask user for 4 distances, from the map.
    System.out.print("Enter distance 1 (in inches): ");
    double distancel = keyboard.nextdouble();

    System.out.print("Enter distance 2 (in inches): "); 
    double distance2 = keyboard.nextdouble();        

    System.out.print = "Enter distance 2 (in inches): ";
    double distance3 = keyboard.nextdouble();

    // determine total miles from total inches
    // Scale:  1 inch is 1/4 mile
    double totalMiles = totalInches * 1/4;        
    // add to get total inches on map
    distance1 + distance2 + distance2 + distance4 = totalInches;

    //round to one-tenth of a mile 
    int miles =(totalMiles + 0.05) * 10;

    //total miles
    int totalMiles = 10%

    // calculate kilometers
    totalKilos = totalMiles * miles * kilos;

    // round kilometers to tenths
    //int class kilos = totalKilos + {005 * 10)};
    //totalKilos = kilos / 100;

    // print results
    System.out.printn("Total inches:     " + "totalInches");
    Sytem.out.println ("Total miles:      " + milesTotal);
    System.out.prntln("Total kilometers: totalKilos");
    {
    }
```

I keep getting a error on all my `double distancel = keyboard.nextdouble();` I'm new to java, and I'm using a program called bluej. I don't understand why its saying keyboard needs to be a variable. If you guys can help me with this error that will be great. I always like to learn. Thanks!

Comment: Just like you have declared input scanner variable and initialized it you need to declare keyboard variable and initialize it before using it so that Java gets to know what exactly you mean when you use "keyboard" variable

Comment: Where is `keyboard` coming from? It seems that your `Scanner` is called `input`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference a variable which is not declared, that's why the compiler says he cannot find `keyboard`.

Just replace all your `keyboard` references with `input`.

Seems like either a typo or a copy&paste error.

Comment: Please, consider flaging this question as answered then.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Scanner` is called `input` and not `keyboard` you should change that when calling it here for example: 
 
`double distancel = keyboard.nextdouble();` change it to `double distancel = input.nextdouble();`.
 I also see another thing:

`totalKilos = totalMiles * miles * kilos;`

You don't have any declared variable `totalKilos` to assign it this value.

You should `int totalKilos = totalMiles * miles * kilos;`

Same thing here: `distance1 + distance2 + distance2 + distance4 = totalInches;`

I think you want to do `double totalInches = distance1 + distance2 + distance2 + distance4;`

Comment: Well.. there are further points.. f.e. "int totalMiles = 10%" and the println calls. But it's not wise to fix all problems, because he is trying to learn Java.